# Preg-match returns a wrong value?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am new with Regular expressions. 
I think that this code should return a 0?
But it returns a 1.

**echo preg_match( "/[a-c]{2}/","abc");**

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're matching 'ab' in your provided string.

```
php > echo preg_match( "/[a-c]{2}/","ab");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1
```

[a-c]{3} would match all three as you're basically asking preg_match to return *exactly* 3 characters in the provided range.

To match exactly three characters in your specified range:

```
php > echo preg_match( "/[a-c]{3}/","abc"); 
1
```

To match where the line begins, has the three characters in the range, and then ends:

```
php > echo preg_match( "/^[a-c]{3}$/","abc");
1
```

Comment: `0` is `False`, `1` is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a regex to match the *entire* string, you need to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
echo preg_match( "/^[a-c]{2}$/","abc");
```